# Number of integer solutions of linear equation.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I have the following problem.

> Assume we have an unlimited number of blocks of 1cm, 2cm and 3cm height. Ignoring the position of the blocks, how many towers of 15cm height can we build?

I know I must find the coefficient of $x^{15}$ of the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{1-x^3}=(1+x+x^2)\frac{1}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{(1-x^3)^2}
$$
How do I find it?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(\frac{1}{1-x} \frac{1}{1-x^2})$ by f(n). Then $f(n) = \lceil \frac{n+1}{2} \rceil$. Obviously, the answer is

$f(0) + f(3) +...+f(12) + f(15) = 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 7 + 8 = 27 $

Answer (score 2):

Define sequences $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ and $\{c_n\}$ by
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-x^3} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n \\
\frac{1}{1-x^3}\frac{1}{1-x^2} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n \\
\frac{1}{1-x^3}\frac{1}{1-x^2} \frac{1}{1-x} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n
\end{align}$$
Then we have $a_0=b_0=c_0=1$ and the recursive relations
$$\begin{align}
a_n &= [3 | n] \\
b_n &= b_{n-2}+a_n \quad \text{ for } n \ge 2\\
c_n &= c_{n-1}+b_n  \quad \text{ for } n \ge 1
\end{align}$$
where $[]$ is the [Iverson Bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket): $[P] = 1$ if $P$ is true, $0$ otherwise. So $[3|n]= 1$ if $3$ divides $n$, otherwise $[3|n]=0$.

Using these relations and working from $n=0$ to $n=15$, we find $c_{15} = 27$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{\text{Remember :}}$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^k= \bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}\bigg)^n$$

By using given formula ,

- $$\frac{1}{1-x}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=1+x+x^2+x^3+...$$ , so the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\binom{n+1-1}{n}$
- $$\frac{1}{1-x^2}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(x^2)^k=1+x^2+x^4+x^6+...$$ , so the coefficient of $x^{2k}$ is $\binom{k+1-1}{k}$
- $$\frac{1}{1-x^3}= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(x^3)^m=1+x^3+x^6+x^9+...$$ , so the coefficient of $x^{3m}$ is $\binom{m+1-1}{m}$

where $n+2k+3m =15$ , so find the possible $n,k,m$ values that satify the equation and they are nonnegative integers such that

- $n=15,k=0,m=0$
- $n=13,k=1,m=0$
- $n=12,k=0,m=1$
- $n=11,k=2,m=0$
- $n=10,k=1,m=1$
- $n=9,k=3,m=0$
- $n=9,k=0,m=2$
- $n=8,k=2,m=1$
- $n=7,k=4,m=0$
- $n=7,k=1,m=2$
- $n=6,k=0,m=3$
- $n=6,k=3,m=1$
- $n=5,k=5,m=0$
- $n=5,k=2,m=2$
- $n=4,k=4,m=1$
- $n=4,k=1,m=3$
- $n=3,k=6,m=0$
- $n=3,k=3,m=2$
- $n=3,k=0,m=4$
- $n=2,k=5,m=1$
- $n=2,k=3,m=3$
- $n=1,k=7,m=0$
- $n=1,k=4,m=2$
- $n=1,k=1,m=4$
- $n=0,k=0,m=5$
- $n=0,k=3,m=3$
- $n=0,k=6,m=1$

As you see  , there are $27$ possible solution that satisfy the equation .Moreover , realize that whichever integer we put in place of $n,k,m$  , the result of binomial coefficient is $1$ , so we just need to sum how many possible solution there are , so the answer is $27$.

I highly recommend you to use wolfram or other softwares to calculate generating functions. I am putting a *[LINK](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2F%281-x%29%29%281%2F%281-x%5E2%29%29%281%2F%281-x%5E3%29%29)*